# Ruby equivalent for C# BitConverter.ToSingle

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hex

We're receiving an hexadecimal string from a client's API and we're supposed to extract different values from it.

In the algorithm used to convert the extracted data the method `BitConverter.ToSingle(four_bytes, 0)` is used.

After a lot of trial and error I've found this magical line in Ruby to work, but don't ask me why ...

```
def convert(four_bytes)
  four_bytes.map { |i| [i.to_s(16)].pack('H2') }.join.unpack('e').first
end
```

It appears it works for almost all cases, but the client just reported a few cases where it does not.

Since I don't really understand what's going on here I'm really confused and don't know what to look for.

Here's one case, like the majority, where the result is the same :

```
convert([35, 55, 90, 67])       => 218.21538 # Ruby
BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0) => 218.21538 # C#
```

Here's the one we encountered were it differs :

```
                                    v
convert([119, 175, 2, 67])      => 160.68541 # Ruby
BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0) => 130.68541 # C#
                                    ^
```

What's wrong with the Ruby method ?
How would you do it ?

Bonus points for some explanations on what happens !

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing rounded values for display?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Where exactly ? If you look at the difference it's not even in the decimal places.

Comment: Can you show the original hex used for your examples, and the C# code that sets `bytes` variable in each of your tests? This looks more like a mistake in hex-to-bytes conversion mistake in your test code, that is throwing you off a possible real problem.

Comment: @NeilSlater I have debugged the C# in VisualStudio and compared the bytes in both languages and they are the same. There must be something wrong with the Ruby method. See http://i.imgur.com/DOpN1a6.png

Comment: I didn't notice the carets initially and only focused on the tail before your edit, ignore me =\

Comment: Maybe this helps - behind the scenes, C# is doing the following:
`if( IsLittleEndian) { 
                        return (*pbyte) | (*(pbyte + 1) << 8)  | (*(pbyte + 2) << 16) | (*(pbyte + 3) << 24);
                    }
                    else {
                        return (*pbyte << 24) | (*(pbyte + 1) << 16)  | (*(pbyte + 2) << 8) | (*(pbyte + 3));                        
                    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby `String#to_i` uses minimum number of digits necessary, and the `.pack` command needs exactly two in order to place each nybble correctly in the constructed float.

So when any of the bytes is 0-15, the conversion goes wrong.

To fix this, convert to a two-digit hex string always. `sprintf` can do this, so the following will work:

```
def convert(four_bytes)
  four_bytes.map { |i| [sprintf('%02x',i)].pack('H2') }.join.unpack('e').first
end
```

Comment: Nice catch ! Thanks a bunch !